# How to write variance covariance matrix of AR(1) process in R

Tags: r, time-series, matrix, covariance-matrix, autoregressive

I'm trying to write autocovariance matrix of AR(1) process in R and I'm having difficulty. The autocovariance matrix that I'm using in my project takes the form as shown in the picture:

[image]

I also formed an example matrix of size n=5 for simplification and that's what I'm trying to code on R. I'm new to forming equations and matrices on R. I have an idea on where to start in terms of forming a diagonal matrix but my problem is in the power of the elements of the matrix, I'm unable to come up with a method to automate the power of each element. Any ideas here?

Comment: @Rali could you explain what your notation stands for. In particular, what these $\delta_i$s are.

Comment: @Taylor the matrix represents variance covariance matrix of an unevenly spaced time series. The deltas represent the time gaps between the observations. e.g. delta_1 is the space between observations y_1 and y_2. I'm assuming an AR(1) process and Phi is the parameter.

Comment: @Rali ok cool then this is not a toeplitz matrix. Idk if the function still handles this situation, though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The covariance between an observation at time $t_i$ and time $t_j$ is 
$$
\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\phi^{|t_i-t_j|}
$$
If the `delta`'s are time gaps between the time points $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_5$, then each $t_i$ are given by cumulative sums of the `delta`'s.  In R do

```
delta <- c(0,1,3,4,8)
phi <- .5
sigma <- 1
t <- cumsum(delta)
Sigma <- sigma^2/(1-phi^2)*phi^abs(outer(t,t,"-"))
```

Comment: Thank you! using the `cumsum` for the powers vector followed by `outer` solved the problem.

Comment: Is this true for AR(1) specifically? Do you have a recommendation for further reading?

Comment: Yes, the above equation is only true for an AR(1) model.  For further reading, search this site for "time series textbook".