# Covariance matrix of autoregressive process, any order

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Consider the model $$x_i=\rho_1x_{i-1}+\rho_2x_{i-2}+\dots+\rho_px_{i-p}+\omega_i,\:\mathbf{\omega}\sim N(\vec0,\mathbf{I}\sigma^2)$$

In the case of order 1 autocorrelation (i.e. where $\rho_2$ and up are 0), I am able to make a covariance matrix of $\mathbf{x}$ quite easily (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295102/how-to-write-variance-covariance-matrix-of-ar1-process-in-r)). But I need to be able to compute the variances and covariances for any order of autocorrelation, and I have not been able to find any literature that covers the math behind it. Does anyone know where I can find out how to compute this matrix?

Comment: The "math behind it" is matrix algebra.  Using it will reveal the inherent patterns and make easy work of the calculations (compared to writing out all the sums).  But I notice your notation for $\omega$ strongly implies $x_i$ is *vector* valued: is that what you intend?

Comment: I meant for $\mathbf{\omega}$ to denote the vector of iid error values, $\mathbf{x}$ to denote the vector of values coming out of the AR process, and $\omega_i$ and $x_i$ to denote individual entries within those vectors